# How do I instantiate a boost::date_time::time_duration with nanoseconds?

Tags: boost, boost-date-time

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.  I can easily make a time_duration with milliseconds, microseconds, or seconds by doing:

```
time_duration t1 = seconds(1);
time_duration t2 = milliseconds(1000);
time_duration t3 = microseconds(1000000);
```

But there's no function for nanoseconds.  What's the trick to converting a plain integer nanoseconds value to a time_duration?

I'm on amd64 architecture on Debian Linux.  Boost version 1.55.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::posix_time::microseconds` is actually `subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000>`. So...

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using nanoseconds = boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000000>;
int main() {
    boost::posix_time::time_duration t = nanoseconds(1000000000);

    std::cout << t << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
00:00:01
```

### UPDATE

Indeed, in the [Compile Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/date_time/details.html#compile_options) for the Boost DateTime library you can see that there's an option to select nanosecond resolution:

> By default the posix_time system uses a single 64 bit integer
>   internally to provide a microsecond level resolution. As an
>   alternative, a combination of a 64 bit integer and a 32 bit integer
>   (96 bit resolution) can be used to provide nano-second level
>   resolutions. The default implementation may provide better performance
>   and more compact memory usage for many applications that do not
>   require nano-second resolutions.
>
> To use the alternate resolution (96 bit nanosecond) the variable
>   `BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG` must be defined in the library
>   users project files (ie Makefile, Jamfile, etc). This macro is not
>   used by the Gregorian system and therefore has no effect when building
>   the library.

Indeed, you can check it using:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1f9a99debc9cbd6)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    std::cout << nanoseconds(1000000000) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason the library doesn't define it that way?

Comment: @mpr I suppose the default library config uses microsecond resolution http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html

Comment: Updated the answer with the documented switch to use nano-second resolution  (beware with ABI compatibility and ODR issues. Always use the flag as documented, in building the entire library and dependent translation units!)